# How to determine branch name before initial commit?

Tags: git

I am trying to make a script that will simplify some common tasks with Git.
Among others, the script should be able to determine the name of the current branch. This works fine if the user has already commited something to the repository, but I am not able to figure out how to do this if the user has not comitted anything yet. For example, in an empty folder:

```
git init
git checkout -b work
```

Now I would like to determine the name of the current branch: (So expected output would be `work`)

```
git branch
```

gives no output. Whereas:

```
git checkout work
```

gives

```
error: pathspec 'work' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

and

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

gives output:

```
HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the     
working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

However,

```
cat .git/HEAD
```

gives me:

```
ref: refs/heads/work
```

but this seems little bit like a hack (peeking into the private directory `.git`). Is there any portable way to determine the branch name when the user has not committed anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supported command that tells you the same thing as `cat .git/HEAD` is `git symbolic-ref HEAD`. Inside a newly inited repository without any commits, it will still print `refs/heads/master`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just because you haven't committed anything yet. Notice that there isn't a `master` yet either. In git branches are just pointers to commits, so without a commit they don't exist. As soon as you commit something (a README or LICENSE is a good place to start) you'll be able to see your branch.

The reason that `.git/HEAD` outputs what you expect is that it's basically a symlink pointing to a branch, even if that branch doesn't exist. This is the promise portion of creating a new orphan branch (an orphan branch is any  branch being created without a previously existing commit, so all branches created between `git init` and `git commit` are orphan branches): Any `git commit` run while the branch doesn't exist will be created on the branch referenced by `.git/HEAD`, creating that branch if it doesn't exist yet.

If you want to determine what `.git/HEAD` is pointed at without running `cat .git/HEAD` you can use the command `git symbolic-ref HEAD`. If you just want the actual branch name you can pass the `--short` flag: `git symbolic-ref HEAD --short`.

Comment: Ok fine.. but the user created a branch with `git checkout -b work`, so the goal is still to determine that branch name.. what you say is that there is no git command to determine that name when the user has not committed anything yet?